# javascript json to python flask

Tags: javascript, python

I have a dynamic editable table.
Once the user finished the edit with the submit button i need to send JSON stringify data to python flask.

This is the javascript that on button click create the alert with the JSON object... what should i add in the same function to send this data to python flask and render an Html template?

```
$(function () {
$("[id*=btnFirstGenerateJson").click(function () {
    var array1 = {};
    $("[id*=tblfirstTable] .DataRow").each(function () {

        var option = $(this).find('td').eq(1).find('select').children("option:selected")

        if(option.length>0){
            value = option.text();
        } else {
            value = $(this).find('td').eq(1).text().trim();
        }

        if (value!=undefined) {

            k = $(this).find('td').eq(0).text().trim();
            value = value.replace(/\t/g, '');
            value = value.replace('\n',' ');
            array1[k]=value
        }
    });
    alert(JSON.stringify(array1));
});
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your code snippet in your Javascript:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var data = JSON.stringify(array1);
#Send the json data using the xhr variable
xhr.send(data);
```

Then in your flask application, you can retrieve the json files by using this code snippet inside your flask application:

```
@app.route('/flask_page',methods=[ "GET",'POST'])
def uploadLabel():
    #Retrieve the json file using request.files.get method of flask
    json_file = request.files.get('file')
    print(json_file)
    print(json_file.filename)
    json_file.save("./"+json_file.filename)
```